# Get current flash version (jquery etc)

Tags: jquery, flash, get, client, version

I want to get my clients current Flash version.
I've managed to get IF the clients computer supports Flash, but not what version he/she has installed.

Thanks in advance!

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
      $(document).ready(function() {  
      if ($.browser.flash == true)  
           $("#gotFlash").html("Flash supported");  
      else  
           $("#gotFlash").html("Flash not supported);  
      });  
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use expressInstall.swf that you can get pretty readily from Adobe and other Flash sites. That will let you display a message depending on what version they have installed

EDIT:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/express_install.html

See the flash player detection kit